# Value of type '1-dimensional array' error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, wcf, object

I am creating a WCF service and one item in the service is an Enum class named County with a list of counties in this state. Another item is an Object class named Person using an array of this Enum (for business reasons an array is needed, not just a single County.) This is not the only array in this service that I am using, but the other arrays involve other objects, not an enum, and work just fine.

I am getting the following error:

`Value of type '1-dimensional array of type LAService.County' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of type LAService.County?' because 'LAService.County' is not derived from 'County?'`.

What are the `'?'` for? I've had this error occur before because of using the wrong types, but the question mark is a new thing. How do I get past this error?

My code:

```
Public Enum County
   Acadia
   Allen
   Ascension
   ...and on and on...
End Enum

<DataContract>
Public Class Person
   <DataMember()>
   Public ServiceCounty() As Nullable(Of County)
   ...and on and on...
End Class

Public Function FillPerson(ds as DataSet) As Person
   Dim sPerson as Person
   Dim iCounty as Integer = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("COUNTY")
   Dim eCounty As String = eval.GetCounty(iCounty)     'This evaluates the county number to a county name string
   Dim sCounty As String = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(County), eCounty), County)
   Dim counties(0) As County
   counties(0) = sCounty
   sPerson = New Person With{.ServiceCounty = counties}
   Return sPerson
End Function
```

Before I build the code, Visual Studios shows the above error at the '`sPerson = New Person With{.ServiceCounty = counties}`' line at the word '`counties`'. Agains, all of my other arrays being used are created the same way but using Objects instead of Enums. I've already tried to change my `Dim sCounty as String` to `Dim sCounty As County` but I get the same error. I've also tried to get rid of the `DirectCast` line and just use `Dim sCounty As County = County.Acadia` and still got the error.

Answer (score 1):

The `?` is shorthand for `Nullable(Of T)`.  For instance, `Dim x As Nullable(Of Integer)` means the same thing as `Dim x As Integer?`.  So, you can fix it by changing this line:

```
Dim counties(0) As County
```

To this:

```
Dim counties(0) As Nullable(Of County)
```

Or, more succinctly, this:

```
Dim counties(0) As County?
```

Comment: Ahhh, it's the first time I've ever had to use Nullable. I just wanted to be able to not have the County property be required. Now I know (and knowing is half the battle.)

Comment: The ? means the same thing in VB.Net